# DJI Camera position w.r.t to Phatom DJI 4 position

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Is is possible to know the `DJI` Phantom 4 camera position w.r.t the drone position. My preception is that we can get `lat` `long` and `altitude` of the drone from the `SDK`, and also the drone position in xyz pitch and yaw is set to (0,0,0) from the home location locked by the phantom 4.

Now, how can we get the position of the camera with respect to drone position?

Lets assume we get pitch, yaw, and roll of the camera device w.r.t to the drone headings, but what about the exact location i.e. distance R from the camera gimbal to the drone position (x,y,z ) in the drone coordinate system or world coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but this will be found under Gimbal APIs and not Camera.  For example method [getYawRelativeToAircraftHeading](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Gimbal/DJIGimbal.html#djigimbal_gimbalstate_yawrelativetoaircraftheading_inline) will return the angle between gimbal and the drone heading.